# How to Webmaster Tools API Share Access?

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to programmatically gain full or restricted access to sites, i.e. share access, to my webmaster tools account?

What I'd like to do is detailed here: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/03/safely-share-access-to-your-site-in.html. However I want to be able to do this with Google's API. Is this possible?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/webmasters/v3/) doesn't expose any endpoints for sharing access with other users.